# Is anyone using Network Solutions SharePoint product?

Tags: wss-3.0, hosting, search

Network Solutions offer a hosted WSS 3.0 environment with a domain name so I thought this would be an ideal (cheap) entry to SharePoint, however, I am facing a lot of issues with it and the only support they offer is to make sure that the server is OK and that SharePoint "is running ok".

One major issue is that they do not have indexing enabled so the search function does not work!

My question, therefore, is "Does anyone use this solution and if so what issues and workarounds have you had to use?"

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit surprised to understand that you are going with Network Solutions for Sharepoint service. As far as I am concerned, they are not the "real player" in Sharepoint solutions.

If you like, you can contact [FPWeb.net](http://www.FPWeb.net) or [ASPHostCentral.com](http://www.asphostcentral.com/Windows-Sharepoint-2010-Hosting.aspx), whose businesses are more focused in providing Sharepoint Solutions for customers. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I agree that their support probably should only go as far as server health - any solution you develop on there is up to you (Sandbox!!) and the support you get for the development of that is in reality out here, not with them (they probably don't have SharePoint developers providing support to their customers).

However - no indexing? Sounds like they're tight on resources and don't want the index service to slow down their infrastructure, which if that is an issue, it could be in a "bad" state (bad as in, physical infrastructure not optimised properly for tenancy).